# Extract Text Between Two Strings Repeatedly in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I'm one of many AppleScript beginners here, it's now going on 3am here and I've done all the possible reading I can, I still have not found my answer. Hopefully some experts can shed some light.

I'm looking to extract multiple values that are between two strings from a block of html code REPEATEDLY. (The block of html string obtained by using javascript to look for a particular id/class from a site)

After hours of searching/reading, I've found many discussing this using Applescript's Text Item Delimiters. However, so far, all of them does one and one time only.

I thought repeat statement may be my answer but doesn't seem to really apply here. (But most likely because I'm so noob)

By far this is the most commonly used method

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to startText
set text1 to text item 1 of InputString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to endText
set text2 to text item 2 of InputString
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
```

Problem is, it only executes once and doesn't care if there are multiple start/end strings in the input string.

In this post [Applescript to remove all text not between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46170073/), someone gave a simple shell script that achieved what the OP was asking for (and by far the closest to what I'm looking to do). I wish I can take that but I've no idea how to change a shell script as a noob.

Thank you so much!

EDIT:
At one of the expert's request, I'm adding sample string and expected output to demonstrate my goal.

```
<div class="table-1"><div class="row"><div class="table-3">Customer ID:</div><div class="table-5">1234567890</div></div><div id="title" class="row"><div class="table-3">Title:</div><div class="table-5"></div></div><div id="customer-name" class="row"><div class="table-3">Name:</div><div class="table-5"><span>FirstName LastName</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></div><div id="primary-email" class="row"><div class="table-3">Primary Email:</div><div class="table-5">test_123@google.com</div></div><div id="customer-email" class="row"><div class="table-3">Account Email:</div><div class="table-5">test_abc@google.com</div></div></div>
```

Goal is to obtain the customer ID, name and account email.

With the method provided by wch1zpink, I was able to erase all the html strings but then it presents a greater problem as now I have all of the values I need as one long string that cannot be separated. I understand this is no easy task to tackle and I may not be approaching this in right direction at all. I greatly appreciate all of your kind help!

PS.
I thought about having the script find any text that appears between a ">" and "<". If "><" this happens, there is no value and move on. At the end it should give me the values I need plus some such as "Name:" or "Title:". Then if the output can be itemized as a list, I can then grab the item by its number. Ofc, just a noob talk, I wish I know how.

EDIT2:
Instead of extracting 3 values all at once from a long inconsistent block of string, I've decided to utilize different methods to extract each values individually and tentatively achieved my goal. The erase method provided by wch1zpink is proven to be very helpful. Once again thank you all for chipping in!

PSS.
I welcome any future additional comments/feedback/suggestions! :D

Comment: Text item delimiters and the shell script you referenced will both act on all occurrences in the given string.  Text item delimiters can also split on multiple delimiting strings.  Can you edit your question to provide a sample input and expected output of what you are looking for?

Comment: @red_menace thank you for commenting! I've tentatively found the solution by not seeking multiple values at once from a long and inconsistent block of string. Thank you so much!

Comment: You might consider posting your solution for those searching for a similar answer.  I just cheated by using [textutil](https://ss64.com/osx/textutil.html) to convert the HTML to plain text, and dumped the resulting paragraphs to a dictionary/record where you can just get the keys you want.

Comment: _"The block of html string obtained by using javascript to look for a particular id/class from a site"_  In that case, perform the text filtering in JavaScript as well, which will be faster and give you access to powerful text manipulation methods that use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
-- Define Source Text Here
set fullTextString to "<p>I thought repeat statement</p> <p>After hours of searching/reading</p>"

-- Define As Many Strings As You Want Removed Here
set removeFromFullTextString to {"<p>", "</p>"}

set cleanedText to stripOuterTextTID(fullTextString, removeFromFullTextString)

on stripOuterTextTID(fullTextString, removeFromFullTextString)
    set originalText to fullTextString
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to removeFromFullTextString
    set tempText to text items of originalText
    set text item delimiters to ""
    set cleanedText to tempText as text
end stripOuterTextTID
```

Comment: This is brilliant!! I will certainly add this to the collections of methods!! The only issue is that I failed to mention is the values I am trying to extract from the block of html string. I've edited my question per red_menace's request to provide more insight. Truly appreciate the method you've provided!

Comment: Hi @wch1zpink thank you so much for offering this method. In fact, after trying out with different search method and combining your erase method, I've come up with the solution. Credit has been given. MUCH appreciated it!

Comment: @DrewCanaima you may find this link is quite valuable.   http://www.cubemg.com/how-to-extract-information-from-a-website-using-applescript/

Comment: I actually used a whole lot of scripts from exactly that blog haha I have even reached out to the blog owner but he/she is probably no longer operating the blog. Thank you!!